# Wait() in Pywinauto does not really wait till "timeout" seconds, what am i missing?

Tags: pywinauto

Here is my code...

```
 app = pywinauto.Application()

window = app.window_(title_re='Some Form', class_name='Some:form').Wait('visible', timeout=20, retry_interval=1)
window.SetFocus()
```

I intentionally closed the form/screen to see if python will wait 20 seconds to show **"pywinauto.findwindows.WindowNotFoundError"**, only after 5 seconds, i can see the error, what am i missing please tell me?
any answers are appreciated.

Comment: Which version do you use? We had a bug in waiting methods some time ago. But in pywinauto 0.6.3 it should work.

Comment: Pywinauto 0.6.3, All i am looking for is to look and wait until the window becomes Active, are there are any options?   tried below options but no luck.....                                                                                            #window = pywinauto.timings.WaitUntilPasses(10, 1, lambda: app.Window_(title=screen), "Screen cannot be reached")

#window = pywinauto.timings.WaitUntilPasses(timeout=10, retry_interval=1, lambda: app.window_(title=screen))                     #window = app.Window_(title_re='System Form Maintenance').Wait('visible', timeout=20, retry_interval=1)

Comment: OK, I need to perform some experiments with `.wait('active')`. It should work and be auto-tested. But I'm curious what could be wrong for such a simple case...

Comment: Hmm... I tried pretty the same on the latest master branch and it works perfectly. I close Notepad window and it's waiting for ~20 seconds. 0.6.3 contains these fixes + auto tests. Probably I need more detailed steps to reproduce to understand what's wrong. Please edit your answer and try the same for Notepad: post the code + output with a traceback.

Comment: Thanks Vasily,  tried "app = pywinauto.Application()
window = app.window_(title_re='Untitled - Notepad').Wait('active', 20, 1)
window['Edit'].ClickInput()
window.TypeKeys("Test")" showing "pywinauto.findwindows.WindowNotFound" error but window = app.window_(title_re='Untitled - Notepad') is perfectly working....Wait() is not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `Window` instead `window`

```
app = pywinauto.Application()

windowOpen = app.Window_(title_re='Some Form', class_name='Some:form').Wait('visible', timeout=20, retry_interval=1)
windowOpen.SetFocus()
```

More detail in [docs](https://pywinauto.github.io/docs/code/pywinauto.application.html?highlight=Wait#pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification.Wait)

Comment: No Luck...below code fails before 5 seconds.... window = app.Window_(title_re='System Form Maintenance').Wait('visible', timeout=20, retry_interval=1)